# Are these two select sql statements equal? "join...on" vs. "where"

Tags: sql, sqlite

Are the following two select SQL statements **exactly** equal? I usually use the `join` keyword, but I found that the sqlite author uses the second form in some of his document pages on sqlite.org.

**The "inner join...on" form**

```
SELECT * FROM Order INNER JOIN OrderItem ON Order.Id = OrderItem.ParentId
```

**The "where" form**

```
SELECT * FROM Order, OrderItem WHERE Order.Id = OrderItem.ParentId
```

Update 1:
I [found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618007/why-select-from-multiple-tables-without-join) might be duplicated, it seems has something to do with the `SQL89` and `SQL92` standards, but it doesn't answer me the second form is an "INNER JOIN", "OUTER JOIN" or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result will be the same but there are separate purpose of each syntax.
for more details check this [inner join vs where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Answer (score -1):

If you talk about specifically the query you mentioned then yes both will result the same but join and where clause don't give same results. join is used for joining two tables and where clause is further used to specify the data selection from those tables.