# why ON clause used on full outer join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, join

As per my understanding, `FULL OUTER JOIN` is a combination of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. In this case, it simply joins two tables with all entries. Please let me know why we are giving "`ON`" clause for `FULL OUTER JOIN` ? or explain how the ON clause is applied or what difference it makes in the query?

Eg Query:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
FULL OUTER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
```

Comment: It defines the criteria that is used when determining that a row from either side matches. Same as for other types of join. Why the confusion? Are you thinking of cross join?

Comment: [see the doc here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx) `ON is used in all join types except a Cross join`

Comment: correct.. was thinking on cross join.. Thanks!!! got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `cross join` produces a Cartesian product between the two tables, returning all possible combinations of all rows. It has **no on clause** because you're just joining everything to everything.

A `full outer join` is a combination of a left outer and right outer join. It returns all rows in both tables that match the query's where clause, and in cases where the on condition can't be satisfied for those rows it puts null values in for the un-populated fields.

From [@Donnie answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228871/sql-server-what-is-the-difference-between-cross-join-and-full-outer-join)

Answer (score 8):

This diagram will help you to understand joins.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: +1 Diagram is perfect,but it doesn't fullfil the answer no negative anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**ON** is the **join condition** and will be used on all join types except cross join

Full outer join is similar to this:

```
SELECT employee.LastName, employee.DepartmentID,
       department.DepartmentName, department.DepartmentID
FROM employee
INNER JOIN department ON employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID

UNION ALL

SELECT employee.LastName, employee.DepartmentID,
       CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)), CAST(NULL AS INTEGER)
FROM employee
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM department
             WHERE employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID)

UNION ALL

SELECT CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(20)), CAST(NULL AS INTEGER),
       department.DepartmentName, department.DepartmentID
FROM department
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM employee
             WHERE employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID)
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE department
(
 DepartmentID INT,
 DepartmentName VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE employee
(
 LastName VARCHAR(20),
 DepartmentID INT
);

INSERT INTO department VALUES(31, 'Sales');
INSERT INTO department VALUES(33, 'Engineering');
INSERT INTO department VALUES(34, 'Clerical');
INSERT INTO department VALUES(35, 'Marketing');

INSERT INTO employee VALUES('Rafferty', 31);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES('Jones', 33);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES('Heisenberg', 33);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES('Robinson', 34);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES('Smith', 34);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES('John', NULL);
```

[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)