# How to determine ODBC supported join operators - Cross Join

Tags: c#, sql, join, odbc, pinvoke

Given an ODBC connection string, I'm trying to determine whether this connection supports cross joining.

Currently I use the following code to determine the supported join operators:

```
(SupportedJoinOperators)connection.GetSchema("DataSourceInformation").Rows[0]["SupportedJoinOperators"]
```

But this only gives me Inner, Left, Right and Full joins.

For example, if a connection string uses the *microsoft text driver (*.txt *.csv)*, the supported join operators are left and right, and the driver actually doesn't support the cross join operator (fails with a message of incorrect syntax).

Using workarounds doesn't guarantee a correct answer, as I gather from [this](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/02/12/no-cross-join-in-ms-access/) link.

I also thought of trying a lower level, like using Pinvoke with the ODBC API like `SqlGetInfo` or `SqlGetFunctions` but it seems like a dead end.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that a cross join is not the same as a full join?

Comment: Not exactly the same, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228871/sql-server-what-is-the-difference-between-cross-join-and-full-outer-join. But I'll nevertheless see if that's enough for my requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, then using the ODBC API you should be able to query that using the attribute `SQL_SQL92_RELATIONAL_JOIN_OPERATORS`, testing for `SQL_SRJO_CROSS_JOIN`.
 From the description at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx:

> SQL_SQL92_RELATIONAL_JOIN_OPERATORS(ODBC 3.0)
>
> An SQLUINTEGER bitmask enumerating the relational join operators supported in a SELECT statement, as defined in SQL-92.
>
> The SQL-92 or FIPS conformance level at which this feature must be supported is shown in parentheses next to each bitmask.
>
> The following bitmasks are used to determine which options are supported by the data source:
>
> SQL_SRJO_CORRESPONDING_CLAUSE (Intermediate level)SQL_SRJO_CROSS_JOIN (Full level)SQL_SRJO_EXCEPT_JOIN
>   (Intermediate level)SQL_SRJO_FULL_OUTER_JOIN (Intermediate level)
>   SQL_SRJO_INNER_JOIN (FIPS Transitional level)SQL_SRJO_INTERSECT_JOIN
>   (Intermediate level)SQL_SRJO_LEFT_OUTER_JOIN (FIPS Transitional
>   level)SQL_SRJO_NATURAL_JOIN (FIPS Transitional
>   level)SQL_SRJO_RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN (FIPS Transitional
>   level)SQL_SRJO_UNION_JOIN (Full level)
>
> SQL_SRJO_INNER_JOIN indicates support for the INNER JOIN syntax, not for the inner join capability. Support for the INNER JOIN syntax
>   is FIPS TRANSITIONAL, whereas support for the inner join capability is
>   ENTRY.

Comment: Hi @erg, Thank you for your answer. Actually, hidden in your answer is the easier solution that escaped me:  the SQL Level is written in parentheses next to each join: `Entry, Intermediate, FIPS Transitional and Full`. Judging by this, cross join belongs to the full sql level (I have verified it by reading this pdf: http://www.databaser.net/moniwiki/pds/DatabaseSystem/SQL99.pdf.

Since I already have this parameter by using `SqlDrivers` I'm relieved from meddling with `SqlGetInfo`, and my problem is solved!

In any way, your answer is correct :-)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I'll try to remember that for the next time :)