# Looping growth figures

Tags: sql, ms-access, crosstab

I'm trying to generate some annual growth figures, which is successful; however I'm getting looping data.

```
SELECT 
  ProvTotalsPeriod.Province, 
  FormatPercent(([12/31/2014]-[12/31/2013])/([12/31/2013])) AS [Growth 14-13], 
  FormatPercent(([12/31/2013]-[12/31/2012])/([12/31/2012])) AS [Growth 13-12], 
  FormatPercent(([12/31/2012]-[12/31/2011])/([12/31/2011])) AS [Growth 12-11]
FROM 
  ProvTotalsPeriod, Membership;
```

Query should output into a CrossTab query displaying the 4 provinces and their growth as a percent for each period between 2014-2013, 2013-2012, and 2012-2011. But I get a CrossTab query that runs for 4320 rows long (should be 4). I'm also unsure if I'm handling generating growth figures the best way (plan on inserting them into a new table).

Table: Membership
(PK)CU_Name(Text), (PK)Period(Date/Time), Membership_#(Number)

CU_Info
(PK)CU_Name(Text), CU_#(Text), Province(Text)

Membership.CU_Name One to Many Membership.Cu_Name

Query: ProvTotalsPeriod

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Membership.[Membership_#]) AS [SumOfMembership_#]
SELECT CU_Info.Province
FROM CU_Info INNER JOIN Membership ON CU_Info.CU_Name = Membership.CU_Name
GROUP BY CU_Info.Province
ORDER BY Membership.Period DESC 
PIVOT Membership.Period;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must show relation between two tables. Using `,` you are using `CROSS JOIN` making combination for every row of each of the tables ([cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228871/sql-server-what-is-the-difference-between-cross-join-and-full-outer-join)).

So rows in `ProvTotalsPeriod` * rows in `Membership` = 4320.

See more about [JOINs](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

**EDIT:**

After see the relationship and query can you try removing `Membership` table:

```
SELECT 
  ProvTotalsPeriod.Province, 
  FormatPercent(([12/31/2014]-[12/31/2013])/([12/31/2013])) AS [Growth 14-13], 
  FormatPercent(([12/31/2013]-[12/31/2012])/([12/31/2012])) AS [Growth 13-12], 
  FormatPercent(([12/31/2012]-[12/31/2011])/([12/31/2011])) AS [Growth 12-11]
FROM 
  ProvTotalsPeriod;
```

Comment: So my ProvTotalsPeriod is a matrix query based on Membership and CU_Info  (my only 2 tables). I'm having problems creating the inner join between the two. Should I perform it on the ProvTotalsPeriod.Period and Membership.Period? It says it does not recognize ProvTotalsPeriod as valid name

Comment: Provide structure of the two tables. After that I can give more specific answer.

Comment: CU_Info: (PK)CU_Name(text), CU_#(Number), Province(Text)  Membership: (PK) CU_Name(Text), (PK)Period(Date), Membership_#  (Number)    
ProvTotalsPeriod: 
TRANSFORM Sum(Membership.[Membership_#]) AS [SumOfMembership_#]
SELECT CU_Info.Province
FROM CU_Info INNER JOIN Membership ON CU_Info.CU_Name = Membership.CU_Name
GROUP BY CU_Info.Province
ORDER BY Membership.Period DESC 
PIVOT Membership.Period;

Comment: Sorry, can you update the question? I don't understand how table CU_Info fits inside the query from the question.

Comment: Just added the relationship and table structure into the original question

Comment: Ok, I don't have data in front of me, also I created PIVOTs in access 10 years ago. So I am not sure how to change query. My point is that you have to figure out how to change query to make relation. You can check if I am right if you multiply rows in ProvTotalsPeriod by rows in Membership. You must receive 4320. Also I see that inside `ProvTotalsPeriod` you have `Province` why you just try to remove `Membership` table?