# What is CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION...)

Tags: sql, union-all

I came across an odd bit of legacy code while going back through old code for cleanup, and I'm trying to pin down exactly what it does...

```
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) as b
```

It's a technique I haven't seen before, including multiple union selects of numbers inside a cross join, and I'm honestly really confused about what it's doing and why someone would do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: What is the difference between CROSS JOIN and FULL OUTER JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228871/sql-server-what-is-the-difference-between-cross-join-and-full-outer-join)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cross join` creates a Cartesian product.

Assuming the `from` clause looks like:

```
FROM t CROSS JOIN
     ( . . . )
```

This creates four rows for every one row in `t`.  The value of `b.a` in these rows varies from 0 to 3.

Comment: So, basically, it turns  
[column1:foo, column2:bar] into [column1:foo, column2:bar, b:0], [column1:foo, column2:bar, b:1], [column1:foo, column2:bar, b:1], [column1:foo, column2:bar, b:3]?

Comment: Just tested on a different server... yea, that's exactly what it does... weird, not sure the point of it though. Thanks!